# How to parse a JSON array in Android development

Tags: android, json

Given JSON string:

```
[
   {
    "id": "236",
    "fbid": "",
    "fbpw": "",
    "udid": "1400000210033",
    "state": "",
    "fullname": "",
    "house": "",
    "office": "",
    "mobile": "",
    "phone": "",
    "email1": "prabhjotkaur3@hotmail.com",
    "email2": "",
    "email3": "",
    "descript": "",
    "facebook": "",
    "twitter": "",
    "gplus": "",
    "youtube": "",
    "linkedin": "",
    "tumblr": "",
    "instagram": "",
    "lasttime": "2013-05-01 20:30:05"
    }
]
```

I want to parse this code but not getting how to parse. Please advice me how to parse this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
result="[{ "id":236, "fbid":"", "udid":1400 }]"

JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);                       
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
{
JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
String id = jObject.getString("id");
String fbid = jObject.getString("fbid");
String udid = jObject.getString("udid");
}
```

in the same way parse others.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Gson](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html) library to parse a `JSON` string into POJO directly.
For e.g.

```
gson.fromJson(yourJsonStr, yourPojoType);
```

And then use the POJO as required.

Comment: +1 quite nice library and faster than genson, jackson or built-in `org.json` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse this json something like this :

```
                        try {
                            String JsonString = "";
                            JSONArray mJsonArray = new JSONArray(JsonString);
                            for (int i = 0; i < mJsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject mJsonObject = mJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

//                            Get you data in variables
                            String mID = mJsonObject.getString("id");
                            String mFBID = mJsonObject.getString("fbid");
                            String mFBPW = mJsonObject.getString("fbpw");
                            String mUDID = mJsonObject.getString("udid");
                            String mSTATE = mJsonObject.getString("state");
                            .....
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String[] id,fbid,fbpw,udid,state;
    String JsonString ="[{\"id\": \"236\",\"fbid\": \"123\",\"fbpw\": \"567\",\"udid\":\"1400000210033\",\"state\": \"gujarat\"}]";
    JSONArray j1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            j1= new JSONArray(JsonString);
            id=new String[j1.length()];
            fbid=new String[j1.length()];
            fbpw=new String[j1.length()];
            udid=new String[j1.length()];
            state=new String[j1.length()];
            for(int i=0;i<j1.length();i++)
            {
                id[i]=j1.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
                Log.e("id",id[i]);
                fbid[i]=j1.getJSONObject(i).getString("fbid");
                Log.e("fbid",fbid[i]);
                fbpw[i]=j1.getJSONObject(i).getString("fbpw");
                Log.e("fbpw",fbpw[i]);
                udid[i]=j1.getJSONObject(i).getString("udid");
                Log.e("udid",udid[i]);
                state[i]=j1.getJSONObject(i).getString("state");
                Log.e("state",state[i]);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Try This Its Helpfull For You.if you are get json data from url so please store it in string variable and pass it this j1 jsonArray.if you statically parse this string so pleas format the string like above ok